# Custom iTerm appearance doesn't save after quitting iTerm

Tags: mac, terminal, themes, iterm2, oh-my-zsh

I'm new to Mac. Recently, I just installed iTerm2 and I also changed some of its fonts and theme (Oh My Zsh). All the changes worked perfectly but when I close iTerm everything reset to its default including fonts, colors.
Please help me with this one. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 12):

You have to save the settings to your profile on the General tab.

Comment: what a terrible implementation... missed this over and over until this comment

Answer (score 6):

I've solved this by clicking `General` -> `Preferences` -> `Save Current Settings to Folder` after I created a new profile.

Answer (score 0):

Check `General` => `Preference`

Set `Save Changes` to `Automatically`

Comment: How is this different from other answers?